# thycotic REST call returns http instead of json

Tags: json

We have two Secret Server servers - prod with cert from CA and test with self signed cert.

We've been developing on the test one with self signed cert ignoring ssl warnings (showed here as curl with --insecure). And all works fine – e.g.:

Unauthenticated GET call (returns 403):

```
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request GET --insecure https://192.168.100.191/secretserver/api/v1/users

{
  "message": "Authentication failed or expired token."
}
```

Authentication token request:

```
curl --header "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" --request POST --data "username=Admin&password=passw0rd&grant_type=password" --insecure https://192.168.100.191/secretserver/oauth2/token

{"access_token":"XRVpc2S7SotSAVDv...GH8GZtw","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":1199}
```

However we can not get working the same requests on the prod env with cert from CA. Whatever service we call, we get 200 with html document in the body – e.g. (the same examples as above):

Unauthenticated GET call (supposed to get 403, but getting 200 with html):

```
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request GET https://ssserver.com/secretserver/api/v1/users

<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fsecretserver%2fapi%2fv1%2fusers">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

Authentication token request:

```
curl --header "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" --request POST --data "username=Admin&password=passw0rd&grant_type=password" https://ssserver.com/secretserver/oauth2/token

<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body> <h2>Object moved to <a href="/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fsecretserver%2foauth2%2ftoken">here</a>.</h2> </body></html>
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that we have Enabled Webservices on both environments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the server use non default URL ,which I wasn't aware of.